# Send request "post" with hidden field and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

my problem is to send a request in html form in "post" on wordpress using a hidden field.

My code is of the form:

```
<form method="" id="myForm" action="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"."product"; ?>">
```

my hidden field of the code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tagHidden" id="inputHidden" >
```

I want to hide the url is:

> /product/?tagHidden=1 ... 2 ..etc

If I want to get the URL like this:

> /product

I insert in the form

> method = "post"

but this does not work. I have to use "post" to hide a part of the url (/?tagHidden=1 ... 2 ..etc)?

help please

Comment: Please show your **actual code** without breaking it down like you have.  That actually makes it more complicated.  And - if you want the URL to have parameters like `product/?tagHidden=1`, then you need to make the form `action` include those parameters, `action="<?php echo....; ?>?tagHidden=1"`

Comment: My code not breaking, i added 1..2 etc ... because I wanted to make it clear that this is a hidden field. What I try to hide it in my URL input hidden
`tagHidden=1`
and show only URL to the page you visited:

business/product/ **without** tagHidden=1

Working on wordpress with php and html5. Thx

Comment: **Please show the actual code**.